# Exact c# result of sql datediff

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime, datediff

I'm trying to get the number of days (calculated byu datediff) in sql and the number of days in c# (calculated by DateTime.now.Substract) to be the same, but they return different results....

```
//returns 0
int reso = DateTime.Now.Subtract(expirationDate).Days;
```

vs

```
//returns 1
dateDiff(dd,getDate(),ExpirationDate)
```

In both cases, ExpirationDate is '10/1/2011 00:00:00', and the code and the DB are sitting on the same server. I want the return int to be the same. I suspect I'm missing something stupid... ideas??

Comment: Are both using the same time zone?  Perhaps try DateTime.UtcNow instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10/1/2011 is less than 1 day away from DateTime.Now.  Since you're getting back a TimeSpan and then applying Days to it, you're getting back a TimeSpan that is < 1 day.  So it'll return 0 Days.

Instead, just use the Date component of those DateTimes and it'll correctly report the number of days apart - like this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime tomorrow = new DateTime(2011, 10, 1);
var val = (tomorrow.Date - now.Date).Days;
```

This will yield you 1 day.

Comment: this works... the key I think is subtracting the 'date', and not just the datetime var...

Answer (score 5):

`dateDiff(dd,getDate(),ExpirationDate)` Is doing a days comparison. `DateTime.Now.Subtract(expirationDate).Days` is doing a date and **time**

For example

`SELECT dateDiff(dd,'10/1/2011 23:59:00' , '10/2/2011')` returns one day even when only one minute apart.

If you want the same in C# you need to remove the time component

e.g.

```
DateTime  dt1 = new DateTime(2011,10,1, 23,59,0);
DateTime  dt2 = new DateTime(2011,10,2, 0,0,0);

Console.WriteLine((int) dt2.Subtract(dt1.Subtract(dt1.TimeOfDay)));
```

So in your case it would be something like

```
DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
int reso = CurrentDate.Subtract(CurrentDate.TimeOfDay).Subtract(DateTime.expirationDate).Days;
```

I haven't tested it but I would not do 
     `DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Now.Subtract.TimeOfDay)`

Because the second call to Now wouldn't be guaranteeing to be the same as first call to Now

In any case Stealth Rabbi's answer seems more elegant anyway since you're looking for a TimeSpan not a DateTime

Comment: int differenceInDays = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day).Subtract(new DateTime(otherDate.Year, otherDate.Month, otherDate.Day));

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, because the date I am subtracting already has the time stripped out (i.e., its 10/1/2011 00:00:00), so it is returning the same (0), while the sql datediff is returning 1

Comment: `DateTime.Now()` doesn't have the time stripped out (except for one case)

Comment: Right, but given the same datetime in both sql and c# they should return the same value, but didn't seem to - unless I did what @itsmat said, which is subtract the .Date - it was helpful anyway, so +1!

Comment: I won't argue that the itsmatt and Stealth Rabbi's answers aren't cleaner and Accepting either is fine with me. But my answer does indeed arrive at the same answer. Perhaps you missed the `.Subtract(CurrentDate.TimeOfDay)` part.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want the number of **Total** days, not the number of days from the largest previous unit. You'd want to use the TotalDays property. Also, you may find it easier to use the minus operator to do a subtraction

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2009, 1, 2);

TimeSpan difference = d1 - d2;
Console.WriteLine(difference.TotalDays); // Outputs (today):1001.46817997424
```